# Type casting for BigDecimal

Tags: java, string, casting, arraylist, bigdecimal

I have a method return type as `ArrayList<String>` which is also reading an argument of the same type. Now how do I `type cast` or modify my BigDecimal to read that value?

```
public static ArrayList<String> currencyUtilArray(ArrayList<String> amountStr ) {
BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(ArrayList<String> amountStr);
//How do I define that the amountStr is ArrayList<String> and need to place in BigDecimal amount one after another till the end of the List 
    return amountStr;
}
```

Or do I need to do

Comment: Are you trying to convert an `ArrayList<String>` to an `ArrayList<BigDecimal>`?

Comment: @Gabe One method would call and send list of values, for now say two values like `1234.5678` and `4567.1234` to this method `currUtil` Now I need to define my method `currUtil` such a way that it reads to values and place it in BigDecimal one after another to process it. How to define my method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't type cast a `String` to a `BigDecimal` or *vice versa*.

If the strings in the array are meant to represent a number when concatenated then do something like this:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 for (String s : amountStr) {
     sb.append(s);
 }
 BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(sb.toString());
```

On the other hand, if each String represents a distinct number:

```
for (String s : amountStr) {
    BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(s);
    // ... and do something with it ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are referencing it correctly. You can't convert the whole ArrayList as an AL of type string to a Big Decimal.

First, change the ArrayList amountStr from within the new BigDecimal(--); and reference a single String from within the ArrayList.

Meaning you would have to loop through the whole thing, adding it into amount:

```
BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(amountStr.get(0));
For(int i = 1; i < amountStr.size(); i++){
amount = amount.add(new BigDecimal(amountStr.get(i)));
}
```

I believe that should give you what you need when it is returned.

Comment: I am actually pretty confused with the question. The wordiness makes it hard to pin-point exactly what you are asking. If you are trying to make a ArrayList<Big Decimal>, then use my code, but change whats in between the for loop as that would not give you what the other possibility would be.

Answer (score 0):

what i understand is you want to convert the `list elements` into `BigDecimal Array`. If so you can do as below:

```
BigDecimal[] amount = new BigDecimal[amountStr.size()];
for (int i=0;i<amountStr.size();i++) {
     amount[i] = new BigDecimal(amountStr.get(i));
 }
```